# fonts - how does the text gets displayed when there is no font associated to it

Tags: unicode, fonts

The data encoding is UTF8 or Unicode.
Plain data does not have any font attached to it.
If an editor would not have any font support how would it display the data.

Comment: This is [not the kind of question Stackoverflow is for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every UI that displays string data has to support fonts in some manner, whether the font is provided by the OS, or assigned by the application. So there is always a font associated with a UI that is displaying string data to a user. As long as that font supports the Unicode codepoints that are represented in the data, it will display fine.

Comment: thanks remy. so i understand that every UI will have a default font and will display unicode data basis on mappings defined in that font. let me put an example of an HTML page that gets opened in any 1 of the major browsers. The Source of HTML page does not contain any style information. It has content in say 5-6 diff languages. So does this application, (the browser) use a single default font or multiple default fonts. Another query -- Is there any single font containing mapping for majority of characters used in different languages.

Comment: Yes, a browser would use a default font if the HTML does not specify one. And Unicode is too big for any single font to support everything, but there are plenty of [Unicode fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) available.

Comment: thank u so much remy, the explanation given by you is totally perfect. i have no doubt regarding this now.